# How to render an email from database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, swiftmailer

I'm sending a mail, and the view comes from the database:

```
$blade_from_db = 'Hello, {{ $something }}!';
$email_data = ['something' => 'World!'];

Mail::send($blade_from_db, $email_data, function ($message) use ($sender)
{
    $message->from($sender->from, $sender->from_safe);
    $message->to($sender->to, $sender->safe);
    $message->subject($sender->subject);
});
```

and this is the error message:
`"message": "View [Hello, {{ $something }}!] not found.",`
someone can help me or give me a suggestion, since I need the content of the view to come from a database.

Comment: The view comes from the database? Like, the view itself or the filename? A fascinating idea if you're storing views in a DB row. You can render a view to a string like this: `View::make('my_view', ['name' => 'Rishabh'])->render();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @j.steelman 
but the view it should contain, if the blade tags come from the database?

Comment: Ah, blades should be put in /resources/views and saved with .blade.php extension. Make this file: /resources/views/emailTemplate.blade.php that contains `"Hello", {{ $something}}!`. Then you can render the template to a string like this: `$emailString = View::make('emailTemplate', ['something' => 'World'])->render()`. That might work for you but you should consider using the default mail process for your version of laravel. Remember that Laravel is Opionated so your best bet is to create a Mailer class that calls the view rather than baking it all into the controller.

Comment: I understand the part of the view, but I want to save an html in the database so that the client can save their own formats

Comment: Very interesting. An email template editor in laravel. I assume you've already considered sprintf sorts of uses where the user is trained to use special characters (could even be double braces) for string injection. Given how blades are parsed and cached, I don't think the value of a blade is treated like a normal string. If you assume that users are trusted enough to create variable blades, then it isn't that much more of a security risk to have the user's blades saved to the filesystem. But my official answer to your question's title is "I don't think its possible".

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking but, we did something similar at my firm and basically had to basically build our own rudimentary template engine using preg_match_all and str_replace.

Answer (score 4):

```
$blade_from_db = view('your view',['something' => 'World!'])->render();


Mail::send([], $email_data, function ($message) use ($sender, $blade_from_db)
{
    $message->from($sender->from, $sender->from_safe);
    $message->to($sender->to, $sender->safe);
    $message->subject($sender->subject);
    $message->setBody($blade_from_db,'text/html');

});
```

Use `$message->setBody($blade_from_db,'text/html');` to send the email with a template from database.

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

For Getting template from your database here is a snippet that I used in my code.

```
<?php
class EmailTemplate extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'email_templates';


    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


    public $fillable = [
        'name',
        'subject',
        'content',
        'variables'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'name' => 'string',
        'subject' => 'string',
        'content' => 'string'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
//        'name' => 'required',
        'subject' => 'required'
    ];

    public function parse($data)
    {
        $parsed = preg_replace_callback('/{{(.*?)}}/', function ($matches) use ($data) {
            list($shortCode, $index) = $matches;

            if (isset($data[$index])) {
                return $data[$index];
            } else {
//                throw new Exception("Shortcode {$shortCode} not found in template id {$this->id}", 1);
            }

        }, $this->content);

        return $parsed;
    }


}
```

Now in your controller, you can

```
$data = ['something' => 'World!'];
Mail::queue([], [], function ($m) use ($sender, $data) {
     $emailTemplate = EmailTemplate::where('name', '=', 'yourtemplate')->first();

     $message->from($sender->from, $sender->from_safe);
     $message->to($sender->to, $sender->safe);
     $message->subject($sender->subject);

     $message->setBody($emailTemplate->parse($data), 'text/html');;
                });
```

Now you can use `{{something}}` in your database to populate these entries

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried this, in theory what I need is to pass a string with the blade variables coming from the database

Comment: @JulioCesarMontenegro You can pass the data to view like this `$blade_from_db = view('your view',['something' => 'World!'])->render();
`

Comment: @JulioCesarMontenegro have a look at my updated hope you will get what you are looking for.